# Ionic Text to Speech Issue Throwing Runtime Error

Tags: angular, ionic3

My app is giving an error when I added Text to Speech feature in it. Not sure what went wrong, before adding text to speech, code was working okay..

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TextToSpeech } from '@ionic-native/text-to-speech' 
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { MaintabsPage } from '../pages/maintabs/maintabs';
import { InfoPage } from '../pages/info/info';
import { SurahPage } from '../pages/surah/surah';
import { SurahSummaryPage } from '../pages/surah-summary/surah-summary';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    MaintabsPage,
    InfoPage,
    SurahPage,
    SurahSummaryPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    MaintabsPage,
    InfoPage,
    SurahPage,
    SurahSummaryPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    TextToSpeech
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then my html code is mentioned below...

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar primary>
    <ion-title>{{surah.name}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
      <div text-center>
        <h1>{{surah.name}}</h1>
      </div>
      <div text-wrap style="font-size: 1.5rem" [(ngModel)]="text">{{surah.details}}</div>
            <button clear ion-button (click)="sayText()">Text to Speak</button> 

</ion-content>
```

then my typescript code is..

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {TextToSpeech} from '@ionic-native/text-to-speech' 

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-surah-summary',
  templateUrl: 'surah-summary.html',
})
export class SurahSummaryPage {

  surah: any;
  text: string;

  constructor(private tts: TextToSpeech, private nav: NavController, private navParams: NavParams) {
    this.surah = this.navParams.data;
    //console.log('**navparams:', this.navParams)
  }

  async sayText():Promise<any>{
          try {
            await this.tts.speak(this.text);
            console.log("Successfully Spoke" + this.text)
          } 
          catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
  }

  // ionViewDidLoad() {
  //   console.log('ionViewDidLoad SurahSummaryPage');
  // }

}
```

I am getting following error...

Runtime Error
Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute at _throwError

```
(http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:23002:11) at setUpControl (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:22912:9) at NgModel._setUpStandalone (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:25477:9) at NgModel._setUpControl (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:25463:37) at NgModel.ngOnChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:25394:18) at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11171:19) at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12597:17) at checkAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12536:16) at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13239:59) at debugCheckDirectivesFn (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13180:13)
Stack
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute
Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute
    at _throwError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:23002:11)
    at setUpControl (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:22912:9)
    at NgModel._setUpStandalone (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:25477:9)
    at NgModel._setUpControl (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:25463:37)
    at NgModel.ngOnChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:25394:18)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11171:19)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12597:17)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12536:16)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13239:59)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13180:13)
    at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:13535)
    at Object.reject (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:12891)
    at Tab.NavControllerBase._fireError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:43269:16)
    at Tab.NavControllerBase._failed (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:43257:14)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:43312:59
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9283)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4508:37)
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9223)
    at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4452)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14
```

Comment: are you using formControl anywhere? any reactive form?

Comment: No I dont use it anywhere but even without that, I get same error :(

Comment: can you tell me where exactly and how?

Comment: I want to read text in {{surah.details}} as text to speak...

Comment: then why use ngModel at all?.. you can access `surah.details` from ts file..you dont seem to be changing it in html

Comment: can you tell me the code how to do this?

Comment: async sayText():Promise<any>{
          try {
            await this.tts.speak(this.surah.details);
            console.log("Successfully Spoke" + this.surah.details)
          } 
          catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div>` tags canot be acced via [(ngModel)], you need to create an `<input>` tag for that. As following:

```
<div text-wrap style="font-size: 1.5rem">{{surah.details}}</div>
//here
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="surah.details" type="text">
<button clear ion-button (click)="sayText()">Text to Speak</button>
```

Comment: right.. but in case of ionic [`ion-input`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/input/Input/) is generally used..

Answer (score 0):

You dont seem to be allowing user to input or update data in your html..Since you want to send `surah.details`..
In your html As [Vega](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5468463/vega) suggests in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45768305/4826457) ,remove `ngModel`

```
 <div text-wrap style="font-size: 1.5rem" >{{surah.details}}</div>
            <button clear ion-button (click)="sayText()">Text to Speak</button>
```

In your ts file send `this.surah.details` which you set in your constructor,

```
 async sayText():Promise<any>{
          try {
            await this.tts.speak(this.surah.details);
            console.log("Successfully Spoke" + this.surah.details)
          } 
          catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
  }
```

Comment: Code is not breaking however button doesnt speak text when click.

Comment: I am testing on real android app :(

Comment: do you get console log?

Comment: VM12403 vendor.js:56735 Native: tried calling Text To Speech.speak, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
cordovaWarn @ VM12403 vendor.js:56735

Comment: use https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ to remote debug in your device

Comment: Awesome. It works now..not sure what happened when I connect with devtools and use that button again...it worked...Can you explain how? I am new to devtools..

Comment: Cordova does not work with ionic serve.. it only works in device/emulator.. Also chrome can be used to remote debug apps running on webkit(which ionic does)

Comment: Thanks. I will read more on it. Do you teach Ionic framework? If yes then please let me know. I am willing to take some classes to master the framework...

Comment: nope..just another mobile dev.. consider accepting the answer if it worked

Comment: No problem. Thanks a lot.